# Agregar texto a columna de una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```html
<table class="TblReporte" border="1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">RETIRO</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">CAJA GENERAL</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">RETIRO SUCURSAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td border="1">NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE</td>
    <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
    <td border="1">MONTO</td>
    <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
    <td border="1">MONTO</td>
    <td border="1">COMENTARIO O JUSTIFICANTE</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Necesito poder agregar texto en la columna de comentarios para posteriormente guardarlos en mi base de datos

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saben como puedo habilitar esta columna para poder escribir ?

Comment: Cual es el codigo con el que llenas la tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establece un `input` de tipo `text` en donde deseas tener la caja de texto.

```
<td border="1"><input type="text" placeholder="COMENTARIO O JUSTIFICANTE"></td>
```

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<table class="TblReporte" border="1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">RETIRO</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">CAJA GENERAL</td>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">RETIRO SUCURSAL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td border="1">NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE</td>
      <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
      <td border="1">MONTO</td>
      <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
      <td border="1">MONTO</td>
      <td border="1"><input type="text" placeholder="COMENTARIO O JUSTIFICANTE"></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar un input dentro del td para escribir, y diferenciarlo con un id para obtener su valor en javascript

---

```html
<td border="1"><input type="text" name="comentario" class = "input_comentario"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas conlleva un trabajo que veo que no conoces todavía.

Lo que debes hacer en primer lugar es recordar que en HTML no se puede escribir. Para ello necesitaremos la etiqueta `<input>` del tipo "text" para hacer un campo editable.

Ese input estaría dentro de un formulario `<form>` que utilizarías para enviar la variable del `<input>` a un fichero php que haga la insercción en la base de datos.

Por ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="guardar.php">
    <table class="TblReporte" border="1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">RETIRO</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">CAJA GENERAL</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">RETIRO SUCURSAL</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td border="1">NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE</td>
        <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
        <td border="1">MONTO</td>
        <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
        <td border="1">MONTO</td>
        <td border="1"><input type="text" name="comentarios" id="comentarios"></td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
<input type="submit" name="Guardar comentarios">
</form>
```

En el input se escribe el comentario y se ejecuta el formulario haciendo clic en el botón que hemos creado.

Eso nos enviara la variable "comentarios" a un fichero php donde recogemos la variable, hacemos conexión a la base de datos y la guardamos.